# HTTPS redirect for static file in appengine java

Tags: java, google-app-engine, hsts

Due to HSTS requirement, static files serving from Appengine Java must be served HTTPS only (i.,e., redirect from HTTP to HTTPS).

HTTPS only is possible in [web.xml descriptor](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/config/webxml#Secure_URLs), but [appengine-web.xml](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/config/appref#include_exclude) does not support it. Is there any way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no need to modify appengine-web.xml. Simply set a security constraint in web.xml to `/*`, and all files will be served over HTTPS.